# React Component CSS does not work when digit zero "0" is displayed but works fine with other values

Tags: reactjs, sass, responsive-design

I have this ChartCard component which shows the design applied to it if the value is greater than zero but when the value is 0 it ignores the scss applied to it and adapts another random style. I am a beginner in React that is why I couldn't understand whether the problem is in the style or component.
Here is the ChartCard Component:

```
render() {
const { chartProps, title, amount, percent, successPercent, strokeWidth, showInfo } = this.props

return (
  <div style={{
    minHeight : '110px',
  }}>
    {chartProps && (
      <div className="chartCard__chart">
        {/* <Sparkline {...chartProps} /> */}
        <Progress type="circle" width={100} percent={ percent } successPercent={ successPercent } stokeWidth={ strokeWidth } showInfo={ showInfo }  />
      </div>
    )}
    <div style={{marginTop: '30px', width: '65%'}}>
    {amount && <div className="chartCard__amount">{amount}</div>}
    {title && <div className="chartCard__title">{title}</div>}
    </div>

  </div>
)
```

Scss for it:

```
 .chartCard {
  padding: rem(15) rem(30) rem(20);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

  &__chart {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 5px;
  }

  &__amount {
    font-size: rem(36);
    color: $black;
    margin-bottom: rem(-10);
  }

  &__title {
    color: $text;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

And where it is being used:

```
 <div>
                <Row gutter={4}>
                  <Col xs={24} lg={12} xl={12}>
                    <ChartCard
                      title="Active Volunteers"
                      amount={volunteer.active_volunteers}
                      successPercent={
                        (volunteer.active_volunteers / volunteer.total_volunteers) * 100
                      }
                    />
                  </Col>
                  <Col xs={24} lg={12} xl={12}>
                    <ChartCard
                      title="Verified Volunteers"
                      amount={volunteer.verified_volunteers}
                      successPercent={
                        (volunteer.verified_volunteers / volunteer.total_volunteers) * 100
                      }
                    />
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </div>
```

You can see that when the value is greater than 0 it shows the styling but not when the value is 0.
[image]

Comment: What digit is 0?

Comment: I'm showing a number of active and verified volunteers. So when the number is 0, it ignores the styling as you can see in the image.

Answer (score 0):

In the ChartCard Component code, I removed the && sign which was considering the value 0 as false and it was cancelling the whole design.

I changed this:

```
<div style={{marginTop: '30px', width: '65%'}}>
{amount && <div className="chartCard__amount">{amount}</div>}
{title && <div className="chartCard__title">{title}</div>}
</div>
```

to this:

```
 <div style={{marginTop: '30px', width: '65%'}}>
{<div className="chartCard__amount">{amount}</div>}
{title && <div className="chartCard__title">{title}</div>}
</div>
```

Comment: To avoid this a good practice would be using ternary operators instead of logical operators which may give you that unstyled "0"
```{amount ? <div>{amount}</div> : null}```